# A mother has two children. What is the probability that both are girls?

Tags: probability

I have thought 2 solutions but I don't know which one is correct

Solution 1
Sample Space ={Both Boys , One Boy and One Girl, Both Girls }
So, 1/3

Solution 2
Sample Space ={BB, BG, GB, GG }
So, 1/4

Case 2: Suppose the problem  is changed to

"A mother is pregnant and is going to have two children. What is the probability that both are girls?"

For this problem which should be the correct solution from above?

Comment: Your second sample space is correct.  You should write the possible outcomes as ordered pairs, in which the first entry represents the older child and the second entry represents the younger child.  This sample space is still valid for twins since one of the twins will be born first.

Answer (score 1):

$$P( \text{a child is a girl})= P( \text{a child is a boy})= \frac12$$

So

$$P(\text{2 girls})=P(\text{2 boys})=\frac14$$
while
$$P(\text{1 boy, 1 girl})=\frac14+\frac14=\frac12$$

Comment: Thanks Karn. Is this solution valid for second part also?

Comment: @heroo9211 yep both are the same